# Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Whern i fire Simple database trigger on firebase,
then it will shows Error like this :
**"Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value"**

```
const firebase=require('firebase-admin');

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
firebase.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.helloNotification = functions.database.ref('/users').onWrite(event => {

 return "A Notification has been deleted from the database ";
});
```

Comment: how are you sending the notification?Topics/tokens?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What do you want to do with your return string?

Comment: also if you are deleting then use `onDelete()`

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have any asynchronous work to do in a function, just `return null`.  Returning a string doesn't have any meaning in Cloud Functions.  If you need to return a promise for some reason, just `return Promise.resolve()`.

Comment: Is this something new with Firebase functions!? It seem that it did not to be like this before...

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the error to disappear you could simply just

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve("A Notification has been deleted from the database ")
})
```

but it would be kinda pointless to return a string here.

If it's just for testing you could

```
console.log("A Notification has been deleted from the database ")
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

make some changes

instead of return statement write **console.log('...');**

add **'use strict'** at the top of the code

write **admin** instead of **firebase** to initialize the app

the code looks like

```
'use strict'
const firebase=require('firebase-admin');

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.helloNotification = functions.database.ref('/users').onWrite(event => {

 console.log('A Notification has been deleted from the database');
});
```